# Passing Variable from C++ to Matlab (Workspace)

Tags: c++, matlab, variables, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a variable `z = 100` from C++ to Matlab for further processing (this is just a very simplified example). I basically want this to be passed as a global variable such that I can access this variable from any Matlab function, (perhaps sent to the Matlab Workspace).

Here is my C++ code (I'm using the Matlab engine from within C++):

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "engine.h"
#include <engine.h>
//#include <cmath>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#pragma comment ( lib, "libmat.lib" )
#pragma comment ( lib, "libmx.lib" )
#pragma comment ( lib, "libmex.lib" )
#pragma comment ( lib, "libeng.lib" )

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Engine *ep = engOpen(NULL);
    int z;
    mxArray *z_array = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    double *pz = mxGetPr(z_array);
    z = 100;
    engPutVariable(ep, "z", z_array);

    engClose(ep);

    return 0;
}
```

When this code has finished executing, I open Matlab and try to access the variable `z` but it doesn't exist. Is there something I'm missing here? (I've also tried inserted `engEvalString(ep, "global z; disp(z);");` after `engPutVariable` but this doesn't help.

I'd appreciate any insight you might be able to give me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me.
By writng engClose(ep); you close the Matlab Engine so the variable z will disappear with the Matlab session.

EDIT : By reviewing your code, I noticed that z has not been affected to z_array. So try the following code

```
mxArray *z_array = NULL;
double z[1] = {100};
z_array = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
memcpy((char *) mxGetPr(z_array), (char*) z, sizeof(double));
engPutVariable(ep, "z", z_array);
mxDestroyArray(z_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought the same thing initially; however, if I remove engClose(ep); the Matlab Command Window does stay open but if I start Matlab there is no variable named z in the workspace or anywhere else.

Comment: Ahh yes I see - that now returns z = 100 from within the command window. Thank you! However, is there some way to access this value from a Matlab function? When I open Matlab there is no z value in the workspace.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, if you close the Matlab session, z will disappear too. In order to access the workspace from a Matlab function, you can use the command evalin. For example : z = evalin('base','z');

Comment: Sorry I'll try and clarify - running the above code simply opens up a command window through the Matlab engine. It lets you run Matlab commands through C++ but it doesn't actually open Matlab in its entirety.

I don't actually want to run Matlab commands from my C++ program - I just want to pass a variable 'z' from C++ to Matlab so my Matlab function can use it as required.

Comment: Basically I have a Matlab function which runs at the same time as my C++ program. I wish to send the variable 'z' from C++ to Matlab so my Matlab function can use that value in real time.

Comment: By creating a new Matlab session, you won't be able to pass your variable to another Matlab session. So you have to use only one Matlab session for your function and for your variable z else I would not recommend using the Matlab engine to pass your variable,

Comment: I understand. Is there another method which is more appropriate for passing variables between C++ and Matlab for my application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84642/discussion-between-oro777-and-msttm).